# How to add toggle "Show All", "Hide All" to the list of products

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple task:
There is an array of products. If this array is longer than 3, then I need to display only three elements of this array on the page. The rest should be visible only if the user will click `Show All` button. And after he clicked `Show All` all the items should appear on the page and `Show All` should change to `Hide All`

Here is a part of my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="product-class" *ngIf="hasProducts()">
  <p class="products">Choose additional products</p>
  <span *ngIf="productsLength()">Show All</span>
  <button
    *ngFor="let product of products"
    class="product-item">
    {{product.title}}
    <span class="product-price">{{productPrice.price | currency}}</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Component itself (simplified it not to overwhelm) :

```
...

products = [
            {title : "Coffee", price: "5"}, 
            {title : "Tea", price: "6"},
            {title : "Cheese", price: "7"},
            {title : "Apple", price: "3"},
            {title : "Tomato", price: "4"}
           ]

modifiersLength() {
  if (this.products.length > 3) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

How to proceed with the logic? I am new in Front-End.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Slice` in `ngFor` in component.html.

```
<div class="product-class" *ngIf="products.length>0">
  <p class="products">Choose additional products</p>
  <button *ngIf="products.length>defaultShow" (click)="showAll=!showAll">{{showAll? "Hide All": "Show All"}}</button>
  <div
    *ngFor="let product of products | slice:0: showAll?products.length:defaultShow"
    class="product-item">
    {{product.title}}
    <span class="product-price">{{product.price | currency}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in component.ts file you need declarations. No methods needed!

```
showAll = false;
defaultShow = 3;
products = [
            {title : "Coffee", price: "5"}, 
            {title : "Tea", price: "6"},
            {title : "Cheese", price: "7"},
            {title : "Apple", price: "3"},
            {title : "Tomato", price: "4"}
           ]
```

You can change the value of `defaultShow` variable as per your need! if you make it 10 then by default it will show 10 rows.

See the working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-show-hide-app)

Comment: Instead of (click)="showAll=!showAll" I was pushed to use a toggle function (as in example below. And the issue is that when I click "Show all" it switches to "Hide All" but when I click the on "Hide All" it doesn't switch back to "Show All". Do you know how to solve that? I am still implementing your advice. stuck on this toggle issue

Comment: Sure, I have updated the working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-show-hide-app). Please take a look. I have updated it with toggle function

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

HTML

```
<button (click)="toggleProducts()">
 {{showAll ? 'Hide all' :  'Show All'}}
</button>

<product-component 
 *ngFor="let p of products | slice:0: showAll ? products.length : 3"
 [value]="p">
</product-component>
```

TS

```
  showAll = false;
  products = [
    ...
  ]

  toggleProducts() {
    this.showAll = !this.showAll;
  }
```

Comment: I've tried your approach but faced with the issue - first time you click on "Show All" it switches to "Hide All". But when I click "Hide All" it doesn't switch back to "Show All" . What could be the reason?

Comment: Does is hide the elements in your array when you click in "Hide All"? I've tested it in a stackblitz and it's working maybe you have a typo somewhere

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-43czsj?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: No, it doesn't hide the elements

Comment: But clicking "Show All" works and shows more than three elements when you click it. I've checked the typos.. seems to be ok

Comment: can you provide an stackblitz with your code? or check out the link I posted above, maybe you'll find the error more easily

Comment: Weird but it works on stackblitz.. So I will have to investigate internally. Unfortunately, I cannot post all the code here :(

Comment: Thank you so much!